# How to implement Video call in Existing PHP project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, webrtc

I'm a fresher in developing. I have to implement video conferencing. I'm using PHP, Jquery. And i've searched for this in many sites i didn't find any detailed and simple tutorial.

How can i create a room and and join room in RTCPeerConnection. when i try to implement from webrtc guide they've used SignalingChannel() which i get error as it's not found. Need any help in this topic.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share your attempts. Having coded in PHP for some years, I've never come across any concept of "RTCPeerConnection" - are you sure this is not a browser / JS topic?

Answer (score 1):

You don't 'need' to use nodejs to make a video call with screenshare.
I am unsure of the extent of the knowledge you currently have in this field, thus I will put more information which wasn't directly requested from your question.

I suggest that you use webRTC. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/
You can use the getDisplayMedia to get the stream of a screenshare.
You can use the getUserMedia to request microphone and (optional) camera.

When you have the stream, you need to create some RTCPeerConnection which you will add those stream on that object and connect the RTCPeerConnection between 2 users.

The only data needed to connect 2 users are

```
RTCPeerConnection.createOffer()
RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription()
RTCPeerConnection.createAnswer()
RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription()
RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate()
RTCPeerConnection.onicecandidate = eventHandler;
```

You need to exchange the "offer", "answer", "candidates" between both RTCPeerConnection to establish the connection and share the streams between 2 users.

Normally people use a signaling server to exchange those message like socket.io or websockets, but we can use anything to exchange those messages.
There plenty of information online such as https://telecom.altanai.com/tag/rtc/

In short, you should create an RTCPeerConnection from yourself to yourself as a proof of concept, and after, you need to figure out how to forward the "offer", "answer", "candidates" message between both object on the same page. When you are done, you now need to figure out how to exchange them between 2 browsers.

I am sorry if this isn't helpful, I have never heard nor used yii2.
But in php, you could store server side a roomId + the offer of a user.
When a 2nd user join the same roomId, you forward him the offer and he send the answer and candidate to php which you need to forward back to the other user.
This indirectly mean, you will need both user to ping your site each 5 seconds to know if there an answer or candidates to their offer.

As soon as the connection is established, you don't need to ping your site anymore as your connection is fully established.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/), It have lots of features.

It works completely on the client side and doesn't require a server. If you want to generate tokens you can use its SDKs which are available in multiple languages include PHP as well.

For PHP SDK, please visit [PHP SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/token_server_php?platform=PHP).